# Как сохранить pid процесса в переменную

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, shell

Файл `tmp/pids/server.pid` содержит одну строчку - номер процесса.

Как получить эту строчку и присвоить это значение в переменную?

В итоге нужно просто убить процесс через `kill -9`.

Comment: я считаю ответ @0xdb более подробным и более производительным (работает быстрее), поэтому лучше отметить его ответ как правильный :)

Comment: *pkill*, если я правильно помню, умеет сам считывать файл с PID.

Comment: @MaxU, не самый лучший ответ к него.

Comment: @0andriy, `pkill` может убить больше несколько процессов если совпадает _часть_ имени процесса. Безопаснее убивать по PID

Comment: @MaxU, почитайте документацию ещё раз, в частности упоминание *-F*. Да и видно вы упустили из виду мои комментарии выше.

Comment: @0andriy, а если надо убить один экземпляр из нескольких запущенных? _Мое личное мнение_ - `pkill` стоит использовать, если работает человек (эксперт), который может оценить риски и принять правильное решение. Если речь о скриптах, то надо сохранять PID при запуске и убивать процесс по PID'у

Comment: @MaxU, вы точно прочитали документацию, или просто напролом кинулись комментировать?

Comment: @0andriy, [документация](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pkill) говорит, что `-F` нет, а `-f` ожидает полный путьт...

Comment: @MaxU, тяжело с очень старыми версиями софта жить...

Comment: @0andriy, решение от 0xdb будет работать и на старых версиях... Если вам принципиально, то добавьте собственный ответ...

Comment: @0andriy "тяжело с очень старыми версиями софта жить" - тяжело, но надо - never change runnig system. Я доабвил как PS, но не считаю, что это абсолютно необходимо, т.к. -F не всегда доступно.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь подстановкой команд `$(command)`. Bash выполненит команду в sub-shell и заменит конструкцию подстановки содержимым стандартного выводa команды. Например:

```
$ echo 9999 >tmp/pids/server.pid
$ pid=$(<tmp/pids/server.pid)
$ kill -9 $pid
-bash: kill: (9999) - No such process
```

Подробнее в [мануале bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html?page=30#Command-Substitution). И что конкретно касается темы вопроса, цитирую:

> The  command  substitution $(cat file) can be replaced by the equivalent but faster $(< file).

---

PS Без промежуточного сохранения в переменную, можно воспользоваться утилитой `pkill`, если опция `-F` доступна. Вернёт 0, если найдёт мин. один процесс:

```
$ pkill -F tmp/pids/server.pid
$ echo $?  
1
```

Comment: я не знал, что `$(< file)` быстрее чем `$(cat file)` - спасибо за ссылку! К сожалению не могу проголосовать больше одного раза ;-)

Comment: @MaxU уже давно так, ещё с какой то 3.х версии.

Comment: *pkill* попробуйте.

Comment: @0andriy Зачем? Вопрос же не об этом.

Comment: @0xdb, возможно вы не прочитали последний параграф в нём.

Comment: @0andriy Прочитал, это конечная цель. Главный вопрос, как сохранить в переменную. Мы же не  знаем, как ТС её будет использовать кроме как `kill`.

Comment: Могли бы и упомянуть *pkill -F*, а не упрямствовать — именно это   и отличает хороший ответ.

Comment: @0andriy Так вас устроит?  Хороший ответ отличает, краткость и по-существу вопроса, а не все возможные варианты решения.

Comment: Очень точный ответ с точки зрения обучения — плох. В армии, конечно, такой бы пригодился.

Comment: @0andriy Ну Вам не угодишь. Дайте свой ответ.

Comment: Нет, нет, здесь как раз вы угодили, вопрошающему дано как минимум пара вариантов с кратким пояснением. Я всего лишь парировал на вашу фразу "по существу вопроса".

Answer (score 7):

Пример:

```
$ pid=$(cat /var/run/sshd.pid)
$ echo $pid
3528
```

если нужно просто убить процесс, то можно и без переменной:

```
kill -9 $(cat /var/run/sshd.pid)
```